# Condition need to meet in multiple columns before it start the count

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 columns of data **C, D** and **G**.

Column C contains multiple cells of different & similar Phone numbers: such as **6027778998**
Column D contains multiple calls Duration: such as **0:00:30**
Column E contains two kind of text. Some cells contains **Unanswered** and some cells contains **Answered**

I have a list of certain phone numbers in **Column H**. I'm trying to get the total numbers of calls for phone numbers in **Column H** if the three condition meet from **Column C, D** & **G**.

**Column I** is where I want to produce the results of total number of actual calls for each of those numbers in **Column H**.

Here what I want: IF Column C show the number matching the **Column H**, than check in the same rom under **column D** that if duration is not less than **0:00:10 sec**. If both of them meet than Check **Column G** to see if it says **Answered**. If all of three columns meet the need of

> Column C = Phone numbers
>   Column D = more than 0:00:10 sec
>   Column G = Answered
>   Column H = Phone numbers that count needed from C,D & G if above 3 conditions meet in a any row
>   Column I = Where the total count will show

I tried `IF`, `COUNTIF` but I can only count one row and not sure how to check in other three columns.
 Here is what I able to reach so far in **Column I**.

```
=COUNTIF(C:C,H1)
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

1. Insert a new column before H, so what was H will now be I.  Label H1
   "CriteriaMet".
2. In H2, put `=IF(AND(G2="Answered",(D2>0.00011574)),C2,"nope")`.
3. In J2, put `=COUNTIF(H$2:H$7,I2)`.  (You'll have to modify `H$7` to reflect the
   bottom row of your data.)
4. Now, fill-down H2 and J2 to the last row of your data, and hide column H.

Voila!